# Selected ListViewItem color changes in Windows-XP but not in Windows-7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-7

I have a ListView and I want the selectedItem's background be red. It works in Windows-XP very well but in Windows-7 Nothing changes. The default selection for Windows XP is a blue background but in Windows7 I only see a thin blue line under the ListViewItem and no other color for the background. Is there anything that I should add for Windows-7 that I'm not aware of? Would appricciate your help a lot.

this is how my xaml looks:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultControlStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RowBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ItemToolTip}" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF0000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FF0000"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

If you need more information please let me know.

/N

Answer (score 2):

This XAML works just fine in Windows 7, showing the selected item as Red..

Since we do not know what `DefaultControlStyle` that you're based on is, I'm guessing it's the place which is causing you problems.

I recommend you create a clean new side project without `DefaultControlStyle` (only with above XAML) and see for yourself.

Comment: there is nothing special in  DefaultControlStyle.

Comment: <Style x:Key="DefaultControlStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>

Comment: Did you try a new project like I recommended?

Comment: No not yet. I will try that now.

Comment: I tried. you are right it works. It should be something in the styles in this project that causes this. But still strange that the problem only shows up in Windows-7. :(